# What is the difference between React Store to global objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

We can use something like this:

```
// GlobalStore.js

import { store } from 'react-easy-store'

const _store = store({a: 1})

export default _store
```

And use it like this:

```
// any file.js
import GlobalStore from 'path/to/global-store'
import { view } from 'react-easy-state'

export default view(() => {
  console.log(GlobalStore.a) // 1
})
```

We could also create a file like this:

```
// GlobalStore.js

export default {
  a: 1
}
```

and import it like this:

```
// any file.js
import GlobalStore from 'path/to/global-store'

export default () => {
  console.log(GlobalStore.a) // 1
}
```

We also can add "inner methods" either in React store and either in any JS object like this:

```
{
  ...
  someMethod() { // do something with the object }
}
```

Also, when using "regular" js object and import it from elsewhere in the app, it always be "ready" and up to date with the new defined info's, for example: if file A updates the GlobalScope, when we navigate or import file B that also imports file A, it will be up to date with the new data that file A leaved.

In addition we have Redux which is much complex than the 'react-easy-store' that I mentioned above.

So what are the differences / benefits?

Why installing a third party dependency if we can actually achieve the same thing with basic JS?

Comment: Your example doesn't demonstrate a similar use-case between react-easy-store and a global object. React won't update if your global object changes, but the easy store lib will make sure the view updates.

Comment: As for which to choose between easy store and redux, it's a matter of opinion. I'd say, if you're already using Redux, adding the easy store only complexifies your app, but that's only my opinion.

Comment: Why comment it instead of answering it? I am not using redux since its too complicated.